# choose n cluster for chemical fingerprint

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, rdkit

Hello I am trying to cluster chemical fingerprint

I am using rdkit which provide a hierarchical method for cluster, the problem is that I know the number of cluster I want to have 13 clusters so I am using kmean method based on tanimoto similarity score with scikit

here is my code :

```
smiles = []
molFin = []
fps = []
np_fps = []

#mol["idx"] contain the name of the molecules
for x in mol["idx"]:
    res = cs.search(x)
    #get the smiles code of a molecule
    smi = res[0].smiles

    #get the fingerprint of the molecule
    fp = Chem.MolFromSmiles(str(smi))
    fp = FingerprintMols.FingerprintMol(fp)
    fps.append(fp)


#compute the similarity score (end up with a cross molecule matrix where each occurence correspond to the taminoto score)

dists = []
nfps = len(fps)
for i in range(0,nfps):
    sims = DataStructs.BulkTanimotoSimilarity(fps[i],fps)
    dists.append(sims)

#store the value on a data frame and apply kmean
mol_dist = pd.DataFrame(dists)

k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=13)
k1 = k_means.fit_predict(mol_dist) 
mol["cluster"]  = k1

#get the result
final = mol[["idx","cluster"]]
```

The clustering seems to work in a way but I have no idea how we do a the clustering for chemical fingerprint , shall we apply the clustering algorithm directly on the fingerprint themselve instead?

Comment: Usually I would do as you suggest and cluster the fingerprints directly using an appropriate distance metric. A common choice would be to use the Morgan fingerprints with the jaccard distance (roughly equivalent to tanimoto)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in clustering is how to choose appropriate k. Your problem may be resolve as follows:

1. determine the appropriate k-clusters number. You can use some methods such as Elbow,... 
   refer the link below -- https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/finding-the-k-in-k-means-clustering
2. After having k-numbers, you choose the appropriate features along with obtained k-cluster then clustering your dataset and evaluation.

Best regard !

Comment: I have a ground truth and I just want to compare the clustering of chemical structure with this GT , so I know the number of cluster i need to make the comparison, I just want to know if is it a good practise to do it this way for chemical structure